# Problema com Struct

Tags: c++, struct, array

Estou com o seguinte erro no meu código:

> error: request for member 'media' in 'dado', wich is of non-class type
>   'DadosAluno [5]'

Código:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct DadosAluno{
        int idade[5];
        float media[5];
};

int main (){

    struct DadosAluno dados[5];
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<5; i++){
        cout<< "Digite a idade do aluno: ";
        cin>> dados.idade[i]; //O ERRO ESTÁ AQUI 
        cout<< "Digite a média do aluno: ";
        cin>> dados.media[i];
    }
    cout<< endl;
    cout<< "Dados dos alunos:" << endl;
    for (i=0; i<5; i++){
        cout<< "Idade: " << dados.idade[i] << endl;
        cout<< "Média: " << dados.media[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

O que você quer é um aluno com cinco idades e cinco médias ou cinco alunos cada um com uma idade e uma média?

---

**Se você quiser um aluno com cinco idades e cinco médias:**

Então, o problema está nesta linha:

```
struct DadosAluno dados[5];
```

Que deveria ser isso:

```
struct DadosAluno dados;
```

---

**Se o que você quer são cinco alunos cada um com uma idade e uma média:**

Então o seu `struct` está errado. Ao invés disso:

```
struct DadosAluno{
    int idade[5];
    float media[5];
};
```

Você deveria usar isso:

```
struct DadosAluno {
    int idade;
    float media;
};
```

E nos lugares aonde você usa `dados.idade[i]` deveria ser `dados[i].idade`. Aonde usa `dados.media[i]` deveria ser `dados[i].media`.

---

Se o que você queria não é nenhuma das duas coisas acima, então por favor, explique o que você está tentando fazer.

Além disso, a sua mensagem de erro não corresponde exatamente ao código, uma vez que a variável se chama `dados`, mas a mensagem de erro se refere a uma variável `dado` (sem o `s`).